# Pass Tableview cell's text to RootViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am newbie in iOS programming. I have read so may threads regarding this problem but also couldn't figure out what is actually causing the error. I need to pass first tableview cell's text of tableview of `bookmarkViewController` back to URL address bar of `myViewController` which is the root ViewController when i click the first tableview's cell.
Everything is working fine beside this data passing to root ViewController and i am using delegation for it.

myViewController.h

```
#import "bookmarkViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "historyViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Reachability.h"

@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate,secondViewControllerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *addButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *addressBar;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *searchBar;
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)goForward:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)refreshWebView:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *goBackButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *goForwardButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton;
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;




- (void) loadWebPageFromString:(NSString *)string;


@end
```

myViewController.m

```
   #import "myViewController.h"


    @interface myViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation myViewController



    -(void)loadView
    {


        [super loadView];
        [_goBackButton setEnabled:NO];

    }

    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview
    {


        _addButton.enabled=YES;
        _refreshButton.enabled=YES;
        if ([_webView canGoBack]) {
            [_goBackButton setEnabled:YES];

        } else [_goBackButton setEnabled:NO];

        if ([_webView canGoForward]) {
            [_goForwardButton setEnabled:YES];

        } else _goForwardButton.enabled=NO;


    }

    - (void)checkForWIFIConnection {
        Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];

        NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];

        if (netStatus!=ReachableViaWiFi)
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection"
                                                            message:@"Your device is not connected to internet."
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];



        }
    }







    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        _refreshButton.enabled=NO;
        _addButton.enabled=NO;
        [_goBackButton setEnabled:NO];
        _goForwardButton.enabled=NO;
        [self checkForWIFIConnection];

        [super viewDidLoad];
        }


    -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing :(UITextField *)textField
    {


        if (textField.text){

            if (textField==_searchBar){

                AppDelegate *historydelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
                NSMutableArray *a=historydelegate.historyArray;
                NSString *b=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",textField.text] ;
                [a addObject:b];

            }}}



    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    - (IBAction)googleEntered:(UITextField *)sender {


        Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];

        NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];

        if (netStatus==ReachableViaWiFi){
            [self loadWebPageFromString:_searchBar.text];
            [self textFieldDidEndEditing:_searchBar];
            _addressBar.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",_searchBar.text] ;
        }else {[self checkForWIFIConnection];self.addressBar.text=NULL;}


    }


    - (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
        [_webView goBack];

        _searchBar.text=NULL;
        _addressBar.text=NULL;
    }

    - (IBAction)goForward:(id)sender {
            [_webView goForward];
        _searchBar.text=NULL;

    }

    - (IBAction)refreshWebView:(id)sender {
        [_webView reload];


        [self checkForWIFIConnection];


    }


    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

        AppDelegate *maindelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        NSMutableArray *a=maindelegate.bookmarksArray;
            if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueOne"]){

                if ([_addressBar.text length]!=0){
                    NSString *b=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_addressBar.text];
                    [a addObject:b];



                }}}

        - (void) loadWebPageFromString:(NSString *)string {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];





            NSString *googleSearch = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
            url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@", googleSearch]];
            NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
            [_webView loadRequest:request];
        }


    -(void)loadAddress:(NSString *)mystring{

            NSURL *myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:mystring];
        if(!myurl.scheme){
        myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", mystring]];

        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myurl];
        [_webView loadRequest:request];}
        else{
            myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", mystring]];

            NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myurl];
            [_webView loadRequest:request];

        }

            }


    -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{



        if (navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

            NSURL *URL=[request URL];

                    [self checkForWIFIConnection];
            if ([URL scheme] ) {
                Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];

                NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];

                if (netStatus==ReachableViaWiFi ){
                    _addressBar.text=URL.absoluteString;
                    _searchBar.text=NULL;
                    [_webView loadRequest:request];
                    AppDelegate *historydelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
                    NSMutableArray *a=historydelegate.historyArray;
                    [a addObject:URL.absoluteString];
                }




            }
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;

    }

    - (BOOL) urlIsValid: (NSString *) url
    {
        NSString *regex =
        @"((?:http|https)://)?(?:www\\.)?[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}(\\.\\w{2})?(/(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)?";
        /// OR use this
        ///NSString *regex = "(http|ftp|https)://[\w-_]+(.[\w-_]+)+([\w-.,@?^=%&:/~+#]* [\w-\@?^=%&/~+#])?";
        NSPredicate *regextest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

        if ([regextest evaluateWithObject: url] == NO) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid URL"
                                                            message:@"Enter valid URL."
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }

        return [regextest evaluateWithObject:url];
    }

    -(IBAction)addressEntered:(UITextField *)sender {
            Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];

        NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];

        if (netStatus==ReachableViaWiFi && [self urlIsValid:_addressBar.text]){



        [self loadAddress:_addressBar.text];
            AppDelegate *historydelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
            NSMutableArray *a=historydelegate.historyArray;

            [a addObject:_addressBar.text];

        }else [self checkForWIFIConnection];
        [sender resignFirstResponder];
        _searchBar.text =NULL;

    }
    -(void)showView{
    bookmarkViewController *b=[[bookmarkViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"bookmarkViewController" bundle:nil];

    b.delegate=self;

    [self presentViewController:b animated:YES completion:nil];

}
    - (void)passData:(NSString *)data
    {


        self.addressBar.text=data;

        }
    - (IBAction)go:(id)sender {
    [self showView];
}

    @end
```

bookmarkViewController.h

```
@protocol secondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@required

- (void)passData:(NSString *)data;

@end


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "myViewController.h"
@interface bookmarkViewController : UIViewController 
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<secondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;


- (IBAction)goBac:(id)sender;



@end
```

bookmarkViewController.m

```
#import "bookmarkViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface bookmarkViewController ()

@end

@implementation bookmarkViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.

    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    AppDelegate *maindelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSMutableArray *a=[maindelegate bookmarksArray];
    cell.textLabel.text = [a objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    return cell;


}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
              if ([indexPath row]==0) {

           if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(passData:)]) {


               [self.delegate passData:cell.textLabel.text];


              }
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    AppDelegate *maindelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSMutableArray *a=[maindelegate bookmarksArray];
    return [a count];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{



   [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (IBAction)goBac:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
@end
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: The below answer is correct, but there are a few additional remarks I would like to make that are just about your coding practice in general rather than this specific issue. For delegates, you should not use strong properties. It is likely that you can create a retain loop when doing so, so avoid it. Also, usage of the App Delegate for stuff like a data store is discouraged. Use a singleton for an in-memory only store or use the better NSUserDefaults. These are just a couple things to try to help you learn a little about better coding practice, but unrelated to this issue

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method when a row is selected. It should be used only when you want to get a reusable cell actually. You can use:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([indexPath row]==0)
    {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(passData:)])
        {
            [self.delegate passData:cell.textLabel.text];
        }
    }
}
```

You shouldn't call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` method from your child view controller, it is the parent view controller's job.
And in your delegate method:

```
- (void) passData:(NSString *)data
{
    self.addressBar.text = data;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

EDIT: Method names updated.

Comment: I edited the question after changing didSelectRowAtIndexPath function and changing delegate property to weak. Please have a look. I am not getting log messages as -(void)passData of myViewController is not being called though delegate is responding to passData function

Comment: Did you select `myViewController` as the delegate of other? And how do you show `bookmarkViewController`, are you releasing `myViewController` after showing other?

Comment: I have edited the question and posted the whole code. I request you to have a look.

Comment: You are presenting your view controller in your delegate method? I think it is wrong. You shoukd just set for `addressBar` in your delegate method. And present your view controller in another method or control.

Comment: Did that too just now, but still no solution. I think the problem is with storing the text value which is to be retrieved in addressBar.

Comment: Below is the edited code.
 -(void)showView{
    bookmarkViewController *a=[[bookmarkViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"bookmarkViewController" bundle:nil];
    a.delegate=self;
    [self presentViewController:a animated:YES completion:nil];

}
- (void)passData:(NSString *)data
{
    
    [self showView];
    self.addressBar.text=data;

    
    }

Comment: You misunderstood me. Now, delete `showView` call from inside the delegate method and put it in another place, like an action of a button.

Comment: Please do not write code in a comment, it is very unreadable. And what is the cause of crash? It is not a big deal to create a button. You possibly did something wrong.

Comment: Okay,, i edited the question after adding a button. When i clicked the newly created button then new instance of bookmarkViewController doesn't get presented and hence app crashes after clicking this new button.

Comment: I just updated my answer. I believe that the button's crash case is related to something else. You should give us some stack to trace.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/paragregmi/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/810D39ED-62DA-47A2-813E-8593236C6F0D/MyBrowser.app> (loaded)' with name 'bookmarkViewController''
*** First throw call stack:


May be the problem is within initwithNibName function since i am using storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
Another way to do same is by using navigation controller stack if your application is navigation based.
Try this:- 

1.Define a global NSString in MyViewController.h like
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *strText;

2.Do following code on didSelectRowAtIndexPath of BookMarkViewController

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        NSArray *arrControllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers];
        MyViewController *objMyCnrl = [arrControllers objectAtIndex:[arrControllers count]-2];
        objMyCnrl.strText = cell.textLabel.text; // Pass the string value here
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```